# R Dataframe - add a newline or whitespace bewtween two strings

Tags: r, shiny, knitr, r-markdown

I have a data frame containing two columns, let's call them "description" and "closure_notes". Basically what I am trying to do is combine the contents of both of those columns into a single one (replacing the contents of "description" with the merged contents of the two). The trick is, I need there to a blank line or two between the two pieces of data.

For instances, if `df$description` is, "A short descriptions of the issue", and `df$closure_notes` is, "Solved (Workaround): Fixed issue by restarting services", then the result I want as the new value for `df$description` should be:

```
A short description of the issue

Solved (Workaround): Fixed issue by restarting services
```

The reason for the space is for readability. This data will be eventually shown in a shiny app and an accompanying PDF report that can be generated vi knitr/rmarkdown. I want the space in there so when someone reads this they can easily jump right to the closure notes if they want to, but they want them combined into a single column. I have tried paste with several `"\n\n"` as a separator, tried using `writeLines` and `cat`, which work great, printing to the screen, but I want something that will write the result back to the data frame. I am looping through each row combining these two columns, I just need that blank line separating the two pieces of data. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: To clarify, the line I am using for the combining and assignment of the data is as follows: paste0(incidentsDFLastPeriod[i,2], "\n\n", incidentsDFLastPeriod[i,11]). This works fine, and it get's reassigned to incidentsDFLastPeriod[I,2]. This is all inside of a for loop, obviously. When I print the table out in shiny or otherwise, there are no newlines, it just strings it together as if its another sentence....

Comment: still not very clear.. Please post a sample data.frame and what you have tried already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shiny deals with HTML tags. Therefore try using `< /br>` and not `\n\n`

Comment: This led me to the solution, so I am marking it as the answer. I ended up just inserting "\\\\" into the data in the data frame, so when it was rendered in the PDF, this handled the spacing. For the HTML dashboard display, used the </br> and that handled that. Sorry, I was thinking I should see paces in the dataframe itself, I don't know what I was thinking. Thanks for straightening me out... :o)